# UnicodeDecodeError reading string in CSV

Tags: python, unicode, csv

I'm having a problem reading some chars in python.

I have a csv file in UTF-8 format, and I'm reading, but when script read:

```
PreuÃŸen MÃ¼nster-Kaiserslautern II
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 515, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/Users/fermin/project/gae/cuotastats/controllers/controllers.py", line 50, in get
    f.name = unicode( row[1])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to use Unicode functions and convert string to Unicode, but I haven't found the solution. I tried to use `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `unicode_csv_reader()` generator described in the [csv module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).